Error Installing Package: Cannot find module 'npm-cli.js' - Node.js v20.12.2
Sass package not installed
I wanted to create a css library using sass.
I have already used the sass package several times to compile the css file.
I ran this command:
  npm install node-sass --save-dev

I wanted to install the sass package for the directory, but I noticed that no changes were made to the package .json files and the package-lock file was not created.
That's why I wanted to delete npm and node and install it again.
I manually removed the files myself and then ran Node Uninstaller.
I downloaded node again and after executing the installation command, it gives this error:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
      throw error
      ^

Error: Module 'C:\Users\win_10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js' not found
        at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: []
}

Node.js version 20.12.2

